# How to display local JPG image in a PFImageView

Tags: swift, image, parse-platform

I have several PFImageViews that are there to show images downloaded from Parse. However, there is one local image that I want to be able to load when I desire. For some reason, this code isn't working. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
let checkInImage = UIImage(named: "checkin.jpg")!
let checkInFile = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(checkInImage, 1.0)!
let imagePFFile = PFFile(data: checkInFile)!

tableViewCell.PFImageViewOne.file = imagePFFile
tableViewCell.PFImageViewOne.loadInBackground()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PFImageView is a subclass of UIImageView, you should be able to just set the image view's image property to your image like this:

```
tableViewCell.PFImageViewOne.image = checkInImage
```